# JSON validation fails

Tags: json

I tried various online editors like jsonlint.com etc but nothing is validating my JSON data.

```
[
{
    "id": "1234",
    "dataSourceId": "1234",
    "location": "localhost",
    "schema": "null",
    "frequency": {
        "start": "12",
        "end": "10",
        "pattern": {
            "daily": "daily",
            "weekly": [
                'Sunday',
                'Monday',
                'Tuesday',
                'Wednesday',
                'Thursday',
                'Friday',
                'Saturday'
            ],
            "monthly": "17"
        }
    },
    "type": "db",
    "format": "sql",
    "lastUpdated": "2014-09-16",
    "userId": "123",
    "jsonblob": "null"
}
]
```

Why weekly object is showing error, however everything is correct in chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

With this editor we see there is an error on your array "weekly" : http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/
The error is the simple quote, use double quote.

I hope my answer fit you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [JSON standard](http://json.org/):

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.

so your json is not compliant in this part:

```
[...]
"weekly": [
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday'
],
[...]
```

Please replace the single quotes with double quotes.